# NSTableView double click action not being called

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have an NSViewController which is set as the datasource and delegate of a single column tableview which uses a NSTableCellView subclass. I want to respond to a double-click on a row so I've set the table column to be not editable and have the following code:

**myViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)didDoubleClickFolderRow:(id)sender;
```

**myViewController.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[self.table setDoubleAction:@selector(didDoubleClickFolderRow:)];
[self.table setTarget:self];
}

- (IBAction)didDoubleClickFolderRow:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"yep a row was double-clicked!");
}
```

Yet the method never gets called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Rather obscurely this turns out to have been caused by me overriding `resignFirstResponder` on another view, to get around another problem.

Not sure why a double click on a tableview fires a resignFirstResponder, but it seems to.